# Char.IsSeparator - an array of separators

Tags: c#, string

How to get a list of all `Char[]`, for which the function returns `Char.IsSeparator` true?

Iterate as in the example from Microsoft do not want to.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cta536cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you saying you do not want to iterate over the values? Even a LINQ query will result in iteration, only internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that without an iteration. All you can do is hide the iteration in a method (or use a ready-made method that contains an iteration):

```
private IEnumerable<char> AllChars()
{
    // using the same loop header as the example here:
    for (int ctr = Convert.ToInt32(char.MinValue); ctr <= Convert.ToInt32(char.MaxValue); ctr++) {
        yield return (char)ctr;
    }
}
```

On that method, you can then use the [LINQ functions from the `Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract only a subset of all characters:

```
char[] separatorChars = AllChars().Where(char.IsSeparator).ToArray();
```

The [`Where` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumerates only those items of the original enumeration that comply with the condition - here supplied as the [`char.IsSeparator` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta536cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The thusly selected subset of the total set of characters is then converted into an array by the [`ToArray` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you don't like the loop on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta536cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), here is the same ("loop") in LINQ:

```
int charMin = Convert.ToInt32(Char.MinValue);
int charMax = Convert.ToInt32(Char.MaxValue);
List<char> separatorChars = Enumerable.Range(charMin, charMax - charMin + 1)
    .Select(i => (Char)i)
    .Where(Char.IsSeparator)
    .ToList();
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/XgHFRZ)</kbd>

```
\u0020 (SpaceSeparator)
\u00A0 (SpaceSeparator)
\u1680 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2000 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2001 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2002 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2003 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2004 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2005 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2006 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2007 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2008 (SpaceSeparator)
\u2009 (SpaceSeparator)
\u200A (SpaceSeparator)
\u200B (SpaceSeparator)
\u2028 (LineSeparator)
\u2029 (ParagraphSeparator)
\u202F (SpaceSeparator)
\u3000 (SpaceSeparator)
```

Comment: It seemed to me that the list should be prepared already.
And all you need to call one function;)

Comment: @Mixer: That function doesn't exist. The actual code that is called is in the `CharUnicodeInfo` class and uses pointers and other "unsafe" methods to get a category for that unicode value. There isn't a single list of things stored anyway convenient that is then checked. If you need a single list then use one of the above methods (or personally I'd go for the MSDN one). For me it returns virtually instantly and if you use it a lot you could just stick it in a static somewhere. If you are worried about efficiency then think about benchmarking before worrying. I suspect you'll have no problems.